# Moving to another database: "Specified key was too long"

Tags: database, error

I am attempting to move the database from my local machine running MySQL 5.5.38 to my webhost running 5.1.70. However when I do so I get the following error on at least two tables. I am using a MySQL export/import process.

> #1071 - Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes

Does anyone have any idea how I might overcome this problem, or what is causing it?

Comment: After you swapped the database's charset and collation to UTF-8/utf8_unicode_ci, did you nuke all of the tables and re-import them?

Comment: Hi Brad - yes I did - well I nuked them first, made the ALTER and then reimported. But I've just discovered now the MySQL server does not have the required InnoDB database engine, and I very strongly suspect that is the problem (I worked this out when I tried to do a clean install of Craft).

Comment: Ahh... no doubt that's certainly part of the problem, if not the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I bumped into this last week, and it is exactly as you suspect... **your new database does not support InnoDB, which is a requirement of Craft.**

I'd suggest discussing the matter with your hosting company. In my case, the hosting company was unable to offer InnoDB support in any form, therefore disqualifying them as a viable hosting option for our new site.

Comment: Yes, thanks Lindsey, that was indeed the problem. For some reason the InnoDB engine which was supposed to be installed on the server I'm using was not, and I had not thought to check. That has been rectified and the SQL upload works now.

Comment: Got your own vps or server? Check out your mysql error log and run down this check list. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/error-creating-innodb.html